# Why does same program act different in ideone and codeblocks?

Tags: c

This code is designed to find the sum of digits of 100!. I get the correct ouput in ideone but the wrong one in codeblocks. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define size_of_number 160
#define question 100

//Function Prototypes
void initialise(int[]);
int sum_of_digits(int[]);
void factorial(int[],int);

int main()
{
    int number[size_of_number];
    int sum;

    initialise(number);

    factorial(number, question);
    //Getting the sum of the digits of the number
    sum = sum_of_digits(number);
    printf("The sum of the digits of %d! is %d.\n",question, sum);

    return 0;
}

//Initially, the number is 0 so all it's digits are set to zero.
void initialise(int number[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size_of_number; i++)
    {
        number[i] = 0;
    }
}

//Finding the factorial by multiplying the digits
void factorial(int number[], int num)
{
    int i, first_digit;
    int carry, replace, product;

    first_digit = 0;
    number[first_digit] = 1;

    while(num != 1)
    {
        carry = 0;
        for(i = 0; i <= first_digit; i++)
        {
            product = num*number[i] + carry;
            replace = product%10;
            carry = product/10;
            number[i] = replace;

            if( (i == first_digit) && (carry > 0) )
            {
                first_digit++;
            }
        }

        num--;
    }
}

//Finding the sum of all digits
int sum_of_digits(int number[])
{
    int i, sum;

    for(i = 0; i < size_of_number; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + number[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I had problems with some other programs too. Why s Codeblocks not giving the correct output which is 648 ?

Comment: TL;DR. it can behave differently if containing undefined or implementation defined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't initialize `sum` in the function `sum_of_digits`. Normal local variables don't automatically get a starting value in C, so your program has what the C standard calls undefined behaviour. Anything can happen, but what typically does happen is that the variable starts with whatever data happened to be in the place in memory where the variable happened to be located.

Comment: I'm not able to accept the answer yet. The app is telling me to wait for nine minutes. Thanks for the help ! By the way, you read the program and understood the error so quickly !

Comment: @user230452. That is what happens when you read and write code for a long time. Keep at it.

Comment: You are probably asking @ThomasPadron-McCarthy, but it looks good to me. In fact the fact that the error was caught so quickly is actually a good indication of that.

Comment: I agree. You might want to post your program at Code Review for a more complete answer.

Comment: Was the logic understandable ?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy Yesterday I posted a question on there and they said I should post here. Now, it's the other way around. Lol

Comment: I posted a question on Code Review ... Which had a similar problem with the codeblocks Ideone discrepancy ? Do you mind checking it out ? The app crashes every time I try to go to that page to try to migrate the question.